# Unable to open serial port using Putty to bluetooth device on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, bluetooth, serial-port, putty

I am working on a Dell windows 7 Pro 64 bit machine. Trying to use the on board bluetooth adapter to comm with a homegrown bluetooth device using putty and serial port...
The device pairs with the computer. Hoever, putty is unable to open the serial port the bluetooth device is mapped/assigned to. Tried with putty 0.60 and 0.63. Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Pertinent details:

Baud: 57600
Port: 
Outgoing: COM3 'SPP Dev' 
Incoming: COM4
Adapter: Intel Wireless Bluetooth Adapter 4.0
Also has something called Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator...

Putty version 0.60:

```
57600
COM3
8 bits
1 stop bit
No parity
XON/XOFF
Line discipline options: Force on and Force on
```

Putty version 0.63:

```
57600
COM3
8 bits
1 stop bit
No parity
XON/XOFF
Line discipline options: Force on and Force on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that: this is not how MS Bluetooth Stack works.
tl;dr version: forget the COM ports defined by Windows (incoming and outgoing) and start using 'Bluetooth' Sockets (google BTH_* in MSDN documentation)

Answer (score 0):

When I run Putty 0.63, I notice that SSH is selected as the connection type on the right panel. Have you tried changing this to Serial and then updating the Com port configuration?

Comment: Yes, Serial is selected.